# Tkinter: return self.func(*args) exception

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and can't get a test program functioning. The goal was to keep rotating an image until it reaches the desired angle using tkinter GUI. The program runs fine but after reaching to the desired angle the console shows the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 804, in callit
    func(*args)
StopIteration
```

And the code is :

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import time
class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.update = self.draw().__next__
        master.after(100, self.update)   
    def draw(self):
        image = Image.open(self.filename)
        angle = 0
        while (angle<90):
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
            canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
                250, 250, image=tkimage)
            self.master.after_idle(self.update)
            yield 
            angle += 5
            time.sleep(0.1)
              
root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(root, 'cat.jpg')
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you reach the desired angle, the code doesn't enter your while loop, meaning no `yield` statement is encountered. Thus when you call `self.draw().__next__`, there is no next element to retrieve.

If you want to keep the current code, simply adding an else statement with a yield afterwards would solve your error

```py
def draw(self):
    image = Image.open(self.filename)
    angle = 0
    while (angle<90):
        tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
        canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
            250, 250, image=tkimage)
        self.master.after_idle(self.update)
        yield 
        angle += 5
        time.sleep(0.1)
    else:
        yield
```

However I see no point in using the next and yield statements in the function you've made, and would probably have done something like the below instead

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import time
class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.image = Image.open(self.filename)
        self.angle = 0

        self.master.after(100, self.draw)
 
    def draw(self):
        while self.angle < 90:
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.rotate(angle))
            canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
                250, 250, image=tkimage)
            self.angle += 5
            self.master.after(100, self.draw)

              
root = tk.Tk()
app = SimpleApp(root, 'cat.jpg')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can we add multiple images to the canvas so that they can rotate simultaneously?

Comment: I dont see why not. Please accept the answer if it solves your question - If you have more doubts, you can open a new question!